# Grails 2.5.6 transaction Rollback

Tags: hibernate, grails

The main thing i'm trying to do is return to the edit page if an error occurs or the domain class is invalid. 
I have an `User` Object that contains an `Person` Object as property.

My Controller looks like this:

```
Object update(){
     User.withTransaction{status ->
        try {
            personDaoService?.bindObject(person, params)
            person.validate()
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e.printStackTrace()) 
            status.setRollbackOnly()
        }

        if(person.hasErrors()){ 
            status.setRollbackOnly()
        }
        if(status.isRollbackOnly()){
            person.discard()
            person.refresh()
            return render(view: 'edit', model:[user:user, person:person], params: params)
        }

       try {
            userDaoService?.bindObject(person, params)
            user.validate() 
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e.printStackTrace()) 
            status.setRollbackOnly()
        } 

        if(status.isRollbackOnly()){
            user.discard()
            user.refresh()
            return render(view: 'edit, model:[user:user, person:person], params: params)
        }       
    }
}
```

While returning to the Edit Page i'm always getting an Exception that tolds me no open Session to load the person object.

To quickly solve that i added `lazy:false` in the mapping of the User Object but that had the sadly consequence that the whole project runs very very slow, so i had to remove the `lazy:false` mapping options.

Now I'm trying to find a way to get it working again.

Why is hibernate closing the session on the rollback?

How can I reopen the Session?

**EDIT:**

I tried to render the View before setting the rollback:

```
if(person.hasErrors()){                        
    person.errors.allErrors.each{user.errors.rejectValue("person", "", "${validationTagLib.message(error: it)}")}
    render(view: 'edit', model: [user: user], params: params)
    status.setRollbackOnly()
    return
}
```

This results in this Exception:
`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Comment: You can store the person  and user object/data in one global variable before status.setRollbackOnly(), so this can be used to render your view.

Comment: You can also use @Transactional annotations to the method update

Comment: Unrelated, but `log.error(e.printStackTrace())` is _not_ doing what you think it is. `e.printStackTrace()` is a `void` method that dumps the stack trace to stdout, so you only log `null`. Change to `log.error(e.message, e)` (replace or augment `e.message`) and it will log the error message and stacktrace

Comment: storing the object in a global variable did not work also the @Transactional annotation did not worked, both results in this error `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Comment: by adding a try and catch around your method that is failing capture the throwable error - will firstly let the page through as if nothing went wrong - not what u want - but will help u locate the issue and hopefully fix it - i see this sometimes and usually when something u ask for can't be done - typically more than a specific error caused by validation etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an method in the DomainClasses to load all objects that are needed and I'm calling this method when returning to the edit Page:

```
 Object update(){
     User.withTransaction{status ->
        try {
            personDaoService?.bindObject(person, params)
            person.validate()
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e.printStackTrace()) 
            status.setRollbackOnly()
        }

        if(person.hasErrors()){ 
            status.setRollbackOnly()
        }
        if(status.isRollbackOnly()){
            person.discard()
            person.refresh()
            loadObject(person)
            return render(view: 'edit', model:[user:user, person:person], params: params)
        }

       try {
            userDaoService?.bindObject(person, params)
            user.validate() 
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e.printStackTrace()) 
            status.setRollbackOnly()
        } 

        if(status.isRollbackOnly()){
            user.discard()
            user.refresh()
            loadObject(user)
            return render(view: 'edit', model:[user:user, person:person], params: params)
        }       
    }
}
```

The Method that loads all Properties that type is a domainClass looks like this:

```
void loadObject(Object object, List<Object> loadedObjects = []){
    loadedObjects.add(object)
    for(MapEntry propertyEntryMap in object.properties){
        Object property = propertyEntryMap?.value
        if(grailsApplication.isDomainClass(property.getClass())){
            if(!loadedObjects.contains(property))
                loadObject(property, loadedObject)
        }
    }
    if(object.hasProperty("hasMany")){  
        for(def manyProperty in object.hasMany){
            for(Object property in object."${manyProperty.key}"){
                if(grailsApplication.isDomainClass(property.getClass())){
                   if(!loadedObjects.contains(property))
                       loadObject(property, loadedObject)
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The only Problem u can get with this is that hasMany relationships may be to large and that slows it down.

To solve this problem i added an property to the DomainClass which contains the hasMany relationships that should be loaded:

```
static lazyProperties = ['addresses']
```

This property effects the `loadObject` Method that will step over the properties in that List:

```
void loadObject(Object object, List<Object> loadedObjects = []){
    loadedObjects.add(object)
    for(MapEntry propertyEntryMap in object.properties){
        Object property = propertyEntryMap?.value
        if(object.hasProperty('lazyProperties')){ // check if object contains the property 'lazyProperties'
            if(object?.lazyProperties?.contains(propertyEntryMap.key))
                continue
        }
        if(grailsApplication.isDomainClass(property.getClass())){
            if(!loadedObjects.contains(property))
                loadObject(property, loadedObject)
        }
    }
    if(object.hasProperty("hasMany")){  
        for(def manyProperty in object.hasMany){
            if(object.hasProperty('lazyProperties')){ // check if object contains the property 'lazyProperties'
                 if(object?.lazyProperties?.contains(manyProperty.key))
                     continue
            }
            for(Object property in object."${manyProperty.key}"){
                if(grailsApplication.isDomainClass(property.getClass())){
                   if(!loadedObjects.contains(property))
                       loadObject(property, loadedObject)
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To try to expand on above comment.

The error suggests something has seriously gone wrong and therefore hibernate must just close the session.

Consider this controller:

```
 def doSomething() {

        SomeBean bean = new SomeBean(params.long('id'))
        bean.updateUser=userService.currentUser
        try {
            serice.foSomething(bean)
        } catch (ValidationException ve) {
            flash.message=message(error:ve.errors.getGlobalError())?:ve.errors
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        } catch (HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException e) {

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            flash.message= t.toString()
        }
        redirect(controller:'someController', action:'list')
    }
```

The reason it has so many try catches is cos I found for example for a wrangled bit of code I was getting `HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException` but the actual work was done - this made the sort of secnario you outline happen - or can happen

By this I mean try to use a try catch around the service method and work out what is really going on first.

Also most importantly the first 3 try catches actually tell the controller to go on - just ignore those problems (I think they all do in this case) but if it wasn't redirect you could add some clause or redirect in the throwable segments so u go elsewhere for that or ignore it in short

To finalise all of above, [this may help you](https://gist.github.com/ddelponte/4217028) fix your issue

```
import grails.validation.ValidationException
class AuthorService {

    void updateAge(id, int age) {
        def author = Author.get(id)
        author.age = age
        if (!author.validate()) {
            throw new ValidationException("Author is not valid", author.errors)
        }
    }
}
```

Basically when you have finally captured your issue and found out what is causing it, you can capture it before it happens and return your own custom validation Exception.

This will then be picked up by your standard failure and everything else will work out smoothly.

You have your layer which validates and ensures all is ok - the current validation layer you show - and the problem isn't really here - it is when you have asked Hibernate and to go do something invalid - remove something that can't be removed - do something that it can't - this then broke it and caused you your current headache - so by capturing them before it happens and doing above will be how you can work around such issues

Comment: It is all about anticipating certain type of problems and dealing with them - this is why some of us get crooked necks :) sitting there all hours of the day

Comment: thx for your suggestion.basicly that works but the changes submitted to the update action can be lost. f.e. the input for the firstname has the default value `user.person.firstname` that will be old one stored in the database.